# Cannot access Django query string parameter in url

Tags: django, api, url, django-rest-framework, keyword-argument

I am trying to access the `category` key from the following url within my view:

```
...users/8/feed?category='x'
```

However, when I run `self.kwargs` within my view, it only returns `'user_id': 8`.

File `urls.py`:

```
path('users/<int:user_id>/feed', views.Posts.as_view())
```

File `views.py`:

```
class Posts(APIView):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        return Response(self.kwargs)
```

What would I change such that `self.kwargs` returns `"user_id": 8, "category": 'x'` rather than just `"user_id": 8`?

It is important that this stays as a query string parameter using '?'. Additionally, I've seen other people implementing similar things using `self.request.GET`, what is the difference between using this and `self.kwargs`?

Comment: self.request.GET("user_id") or self.kwargs("user_id") ?

Comment: Are these different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Django view, `self.kwargs` holds the URL parameters (the parts that are specified in the URL conf, like `<int:user_id>` in your code) and [`self.request.GET`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET) holds the query string parameters (the parts after the `?`)

To get data from both:

```
class Posts(APIView):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        print(self.kwargs['user_id'])

        # this returns None if there was no category specified
        print(self.request.GET.get('category'))

        new_d = {
            'user_id': self.kwargs['user_id'],
            'category': self.request.GET.get('category'),
        }
        return Response(new_d)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...users/8/feed?category='x'
```

there is why i am also not getting category in post request

```
 category = request.GET.get('category')
```

because i have mantioned action in my form

```
<form method="POST" action="{url 'something'}"> ... </form>
```

so solution is that just remove action from form

```
<form method="POST" > ... </form>
```